# How to define and access the CONSTANTS in Rails 1.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, constants

I am confused in defining constant in Rails 1.2.3.

Here I want to define one of the url in constant and want to access at any controller. For example ::

```
TEMPLATE_URL = "www.google.com"
```

Now I want to access in any of the controller. Then I am unable to define and access this constant.

Comment: Just a tip - you should really be using Rails 3. Rails 1.2.3 is incredibly old!

Answer (score 0):

Add following in application_controller.rb (OR application.rb)

```
TEMPLATE_URL = "www.google.com"
```

and you can access it any controller using

```
puts TEMPLATE_URL # www.google.com
```

If you want to use the same variable in your any views/helpers/models you can use it following way

```
ApplicationController::TEMPLATE_URL
```